# Basic ListView Styling

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I have read the docs and tried many samples but to be honest the samples look like a big jumbled mess and don't seem to make much sense.

Can anyone recommend any easy to follow tutorials or docs on how to style a ListView control in XAML? (Without Expression Blend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main common tricks to styling a ListView are to style the items and change the kind of container the listbox uses to lay the items out.

**Styling an Item**
This basically means setting the `ItemTemplate` in xaml to something that knows how to dispay the thing that is the content of the listbox's `ItemsSource`, typically using bindings.

For example, if you have an `ObservableCollection<Customer>` bound to the listbox where customer is defined as:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderReference { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you might style the items with a data template as follows:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderReference}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

A basic example but you get the idea.

**Changing how items are laid out**
Essentially you might not want the default behaviour where items are listed vertically, so you can change the container control used inside the listbox to something more suitable using the `ItemsPanel` property. If, for example you had an item template that looked like an item from the "large icons" view in Windows Explorer, then you might want the listbox to use a `WrapPanel` rather than a `StackPanel` (I'm pretty sure it's a `StackPanel`):

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <ContentPresenter />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Again a basic example.

I wrote all this code from memory into StackOverflow so apologies if there are a few typos or mis-remembered bits in there.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this 2 part "WPF ListView Styling Tutorial" article: http://blog.vascooliveira.com/wpf-listview-styling-tutorial-part-i/

Note: on my computer, the XML (XAML) code does not display correctly, the < and > signs appear as "&lt" and "&gt".