# How to get rid of ListView default disabled effect?

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I do this: `IsEnabled="False"`the list of course gets disabled, but it also get the white frame indicating that it is disabled. I would like to get rid of that white frame and show no indication to the user. How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic ListView Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426624/basic-listview-styling)

Comment: The link that's provided in other question is broken.

Comment: Well, how about the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this template solved the problem:

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListView}" TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                        <Border Name="Border">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ControlLightColor}" />
                            </Border.Background>
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BorderMediumColor}" />
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <ScrollViewer>
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```